# How can I calculate the median, by factor, for multiple columns?

Tags: r

I must compute the median value of each column in a data set by its factor.

This is the code I have used to get the median of each column excluding the 'type' column. The type column is the first column in the data frame and it is the values of that column that are my factors.

```
quant0 = c(0.5)
Median = apply(mydata[2:1051], 2, median, probs = quant0, na.rm = TRUE )
```

My data frame looks something like this:

```
        Type    x1  x2  x3  ...
1:  Fresh   1.54    1.48    1.88    
2:  Dated   1.46    1.99    1.48
3:  Fresh   2.01    1.02    1.03
...
```

I want the median values of x1, x2, ... for factors Fresh and Dated.

Comment: `aggregate(.~Type, mydata, median, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Base R You could use `aggregate`: Note that median does not take the prob parameter

```
aggregate(.~Type, mydata, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `group_by` with `across` from `dplyr`.  Grouped by 'Type', loop `across` the columns that starts with 'x', get the `median`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
       group_by(Type) %>%
       summarise(across(starts_with('x'), median, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or with `quantile`

```
mydata %>%
    group_by(Type) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with('x'), quantile, probs = quant0, na.rm = TRUE))
```